# How come MapView shows less then Map application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a com.google.android.maps.MapView in my application. When using the normal view I do not get any data in Jerusalem and its surroundings. When scrolling to the same location with the Maps app or the maps.google.com webpage the place is rich with mapdata.

Is there a (known) difference between the Map API view and the Google view of mapdata that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google APIs Add-On for Android is a proprietary product. As such, there is no real public documentation on what data is provided by the various layers (e.g., satellite), just that the layers exist. Moreover, there is no real configuration for what gets displayed on the various layers -- all you can do is toggle the layers on and off and control gross aspects like zoom levels.

Comment: Also note that Google Maps uses a different map tiles provider than the public Google Maps apis do. (TeleAtlas, MapKing, MapAbc, etc.).
See my screenshots here for a comparison:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289039/google-maps-apps-with-mapview-have-different-current-positions 
-> which results in slightly different positions (maptiles have sometimes different lat/lng coords) and also some newer buildings or streets seem to be missing in the public API map.