# How to access my current location via GPS in android in indoor?

Tags: android, gps

I cannot access current location via GPS in indoor in my application in android because the GPS signal is weak in indoor. But Google map in android access the current location very fine using GPS in indoor. What should I do inorder to access my current location using GPS in android in indoor ?

Comment: So if GPS is not strong indoor its same for all the app on device, you should try getting the location with both the possible ways i.e network and GPS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412416/improve-gps-accuracy-android

Comment: Agree. GPS coverage is bad indoors in general. This is not a problem of your app, it happens that GPS chips can't pick the satellites signal very well behind walls and roofs. Google Maps uses several alternative methods when GPS is not available, such as Cell-id or Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1):

GPS is generally bad indoors so you cannot rely on it. Try getting the location via wifi location. Which can be very accurate

You do this like so

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Take a look at [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)