# How to detect the phone moved 5 meters

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect that the phone moved from a stand position for more than 5 meters?
I know that GPS is not accurate enough to detect a distance between two points more that 25 meters. Is it possible to do it using the accelerator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improve GPS Accuracy Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412416/improve-gps-accuracy-android)