# Gps location in android

Tags: android

I have taken the current gps value using the following code.

```
public class GetGPS implements LocationListener 
{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {



    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
        //alertDialog.showMessage("Please Turn On your GPS", "GPS Turned Off");

    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

    } 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {

    }   

}
```

it works.but the values are 100-200 feet off.i want to know what is the problem?

Comment: you mean to say that accuracy is ~100 or 200

Comment: it is off by 100 to 200 feet from the original position.

Comment: The API returns the accuracy - you have to deal with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below link might be helpfull

[Google Maps & apps with mapview have different current positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289039/google-maps-apps-with-mapview-have-different-current-positions)

also try using [Criteria.setAccuracy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#setAccuracy%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You should check which location provider is actually supplying the location. If it is calculated using the id of your wifi network or cell ID (by googles servers) then it could be quite far from your actual location - your GPS chip should be more accurate.

Also how are you getting your 'actual' position to compare with the returned result?